# How can I get branch count on a repository via GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm [working on a UI](https://github.com/djjd47130/GitHubBackup/issues/25) which lists all repositories of a given user or organization. This is using a tree format, where the first level is the repositories, and the second level of hierarchy (child nodes) are to be each branch, if expanded.

I'm using a mechanism that deliberately doesn't require me to pull a list of all branches of a given repo, because the API has rate limits on API calls. Instead, all I have to do is instruct it how many child nodes it contains, without actually assigning values to them (until the moment the user expands it). I was almost sure that fetching a list of repos includes branch count in the result, but to my disappointment, I don't see it. I can only see count of forks, stargazers, watchers, issues, etc. Everything except branch count.

The intention of the UI is that it will know in advance the number of branches to populate the child nodes, but not actually fetch them until **after** user has expanded the parent node - thus immediately showing **empty placeholders** for each branch, followed by asynchronous loading of the actual branches to populate. Again, since I need to avoid too many API calls. As user scrolls, **it will use pagination** to fetch only the page(s) it needs to show to the user, and keep it cached for later display.

Specifically, I'm using the Virtual TreeView for Delphi:

```
procedure TfrmMain.LstInitChildren(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  var ChildCount: Cardinal);
var
  L: Integer;
  R: TGitHubRepo;
begin
  L:= Lst.GetNodeLevel(Node);
  case L of
    0: begin
      //TODO: Return number of branches...
      R:= TGitHubRepo(Lst.GetNodeData(Node));
      ChildCount:= R.I['branch_count']; //TODO: There is no such thing!!!
    end;
    1: ChildCount:= 0; //Branches have no further child nodes
  end;
end;
```

Is there something I'm missing that allows me to get repo branch count without having to fetch a complete list of all of them up-front?

Comment: If you're having trouble with rate limits, consider implementing [Conditional Requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests) so repeated queries don't count against your limit.

Comment: One thing I never thought to consider is the fact that literally every repository will have at least one branch. Therefore, I can always show the [+] to expand any repo, which only then will it even care to fetch anything. At that point, I could use pagination to load all the branches, even maybe all at once. The cost of expanding one might be high, but at least I wouldn't need to know total count in advance. The reason why I needed to know in the first place was so I knew whether to put a [+] expander on anything. But since all will have a default branch, they'll all have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) instead. This allows you to tailor your queries and results to just what you need. Rather than grabbing the count and then later filling in the branches, you can do both in one query.

Try out the [Query Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/).

```
query {
  repository(owner: "octocat", name: "Hello-World") {
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix:"refs/heads/") {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
    },
    pullRequests(states:[OPEN]) {
        totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "refs": {
        "totalCount": 3,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "master"
          },
          {
            "name": "octocat-patch-1"
          },
          {
            "name": "test"
          }
        ]
      },
      "pullRequests": {
        "totalCount": 192
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

[Pagination](https://graphql.github.io/learn/pagination/) is done with cursors. First you get the first page, up to 100 at a time, but we're using just 2 here for brevity. The response will contain a unique cursor.

```
{
  repository(owner: "octocat", name: "Hello-World") {
    pullRequests(first:2, states: [OPEN]) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
        cursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequests": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "title": "Update README"
            },
            "cursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOABRYHg=="
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "title": "Just a pull request test"
            },
            "cursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOABR2bQ=="
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then ask for more elements after the cursor. This will get the next 2 elements.

```
{
  repository(owner: "octocat", name: "Hello-World") {
    pullRequests(first:2, after: "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOABR2bQ==", states: [OPEN]) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
        cursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

[Queries can be written like functions and passed arguments](https://graphql.github.io/learn/queries/#variables). The arguments are sent in a separate bit of JSON. This allows the query to be a simple unchanging string.

This query does the same thing as before.

```
query NextPullRequestPage($pullRequestCursor:String) {
  repository(owner: "octocat", name: "Hello-World") {
    pullRequests(first:2, after: $pullRequestCursor, states: [OPEN]) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
        cursor
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "pullRequestCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOABR2bQ=="
}
```

`{ "pullRequestCursor": null }` will fetch the first page.

---

Its [rate limit calculations](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/resource-limitations/) are more complex than the REST API. Instead of calls per hour, you get 5000 points per hour. Each query costs a certain number of points which roughly correspond to how much it costs Github to compute the results. You can find out how much a query costs by asking for its [rateLimit](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/ratelimit/) information. If you pass it `dryRun: true` it will just tell you the cost without running the query.

```
{
  rateLimit(dryRun:true) {
    limit
    cost
    remaining
    resetAt
  }
  repository(owner: "octocat", name: "Hello-World") {
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
    pullRequests(states: [OPEN]) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "rateLimit": {
      "limit": 5000,
      "cost": 1,
      "remaining": 4979,
      "resetAt": "2019-08-21T05:13:56Z"
    }
  }
}
```

This query costs just one point. I have 4979 points remaining and I'll get my rate limit reset at 05:13 UTC.

The GraphQL API is extremely flexible. You should be able to do more with it using less Github resources and less programming to work around rate limits.

Comment: I'd give it a second up-vote if I was able to for that later edit about the rate limit. Unfortunately, I'm already on beer #6 for the night and will pick this back up up probably tomorrow night. I've seen and played with GraphQL before, but never really used it, and have never consumed it from Delphi yet. But it seems simple enough to integrate into what I'm doing. Especially to get rid of the 90% of repo URL junk that I'll never need.

Comment: On a side note, I'm curious how pagination works using GraphQL. I've seen some repos with hundreds of branches, yet GitHub puts a cap at 100 maximum resources per page, apparently even when using GraphQL...

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm in the same boat... with less beer. This is my first time really playing with it. I've added info about pagination and more.

Comment: Your examples are using pull requests, but that's not what I'm interested in. I'm using branches, which seems to work quite differently. I've tried to add `cursor` to different related levels in the request to no avail. Now I'm becoming a "cursor"...

Comment: @JerryDodge It works just the same as pullRequests. `refs(first: 2, refPrefix:"refs/heads/") { edges { cursor { node { name } } } }`

Comment: I guess my confusion is that the pagination example is different from the original example. The original example doesn't have `edges`, it has `nodes`. I'm trying to wrap my head behind the meaning of it all, but so far it's gone way over my head. But I see I can do `edges` and then `node` inside that.

Comment: After changing original query to use `edges` I can add `cursor` now and use `after` to get the next page. Whew! Coffee does better than beer.

Comment: @JerryDodge Figuring it out myself. It helps to know some graph terms. "Edges" connect "nodes". `query { repository(..) { refs(..) { nodes { name } } } }` is like a chained method call of objects with relationships and fields. [query.repository(..)](https://developer.github.com/v4/query/) returns a [Repository](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/). `repository.refs(..)` returns [RefConnections](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/refconnection/) (edges). `refs.nodes` returns [Refs](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/ref/). `nodes { name }` calls `name` on each ref.